# Difference in event subscription formatting

Tags: c#, events, format

Is there a difference between these two formats for subscribing to events:

Style 1:

```
foo.BarEvent += FooEventMethod;
```

Style 2:

```
foo.BarEvent += new FooEventHandler(FooEventMethod);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is c# 1.0 style of subscribing an event.

```
foo.BarEvent += new FooEventHandler(FooEventMethod);
```

Starting from [c# 2.0 you're allowed to subscribe event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) like this

```
foo.BarEvent += FooEventMethod;
```

above code is exactly equal to version1 code, what happens is compiler will create `new FooEventHandler(FooEventMethod)` in background for you.